# Combine a list of multiple lists according to the name of the lists

Tags: r, list

How can I merge a list of  SEVERAL ("outer") lists so that ("inner") list-objects with the same name are merged in the outer layer.

Preferably using r-base (no extra libraries).

Please see the example data and wanted output structure below.

```
# Outer list 1, with three inner lists
list_1 <- list(
  layer_1 = list(A1 = c(1, 2, 3)),
  layer_2 = list(A1 = c(1, 2, 3)),
  layer_3 = list(A1 = c(1, 2, 3)))

# Outer list 2, with three inner lists
list_2 <- list(
  layer_1 = list(B1 = c(4, 5, 6)),
  layer_2 = list(B1 = c(4, 5, 6)),
  layer_3 = list(B1 = c(4, 5, 6)))


# This works 
list_1_2 <- list(list_1, list_2)
do.call("modifyList", list_1_2)


# Outer list 3, with three inner lists
list_3 <- list(
  layer_1 = list(C1 = c(7, 8, 9)),
  layer_2 = list(C1 = c(7, 8, 9)),
  layer_3 = list(C1 = c(7, 8, 9)))

# This does not work
list_1_2_3 <- list(list_1, list_2, list_3)
do.call("modifyList", list_1_2_3)

# I have also tried using lapply
lapply(modifyList, list_1_2_3)
```

I want to restructure list_1_2_3 to this:

```
# Wanted end result
end_list_1_2_3 <- list(
  layer_1 = list(A1 = c(1, 2, 3), B1 = c(4, 5, 6), C1 = c(7, 8, 9)),
  layer_2 = list(A1 = c(1, 2, 3), B1 = c(4, 5, 6), C1 = c(7, 8, 9)),
  layer_3 = list(A1 = c(1, 2, 3), B1 = c(4, 5, 6), C1 = c(7, 8, 9)))

end_list_1_2_3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Reduce` is your friend.

```
> res <- Reduce(modifyList, mget(ls(pattern='^list_\\d$')))
> all.equal(res, end_list_1_2_3)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: hmm something is missing here, but i added the list_1_2_3 object in the first row after the function modifyList... but they are not all.equal.

Comment: @John The regex was the culprit, it also captured your _end_list_1_2_3_, edited. Should work fine now.

Comment: @John You can also do `Reduce(modifyList, list(list_1, list_2, list_3))`, the `mget(ls())` reduces typing.

Comment: thank you ever so much! Reduce is indeed my friend!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `list.merge` from the package **rlist**:

```r
rlist::list.merge(list_1, list_2, list_3)
```

*Notes:*

- an error in your code: at the end, instead of naming `list_3`, you rename `list_2`;
- you can construct a named list by doing `list(layer 1 = ..., layer2 = ..., layer3 = ...)` instead of using `names(mylist) <- ...` as you do.

Comment: thanks! updated the code. but get the error "Error: All arguments must be named list"
when naming the outer lists it does not work as wanted. 
(also is it possible not to use an extra library - updated the question with this).

Comment: @John `rlist::list.merge` is a sequential application of `doModifyList`. So **jay.sf** in his/her comment gave the solution without extra library.